# how to calculate height of Iframe?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to insert Iframe between the header component and footer component, how shall I calculate the height of that Iframe screen?
Note: (the content of header and footer may change)

```
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
         __html: `<iframe
          class="iFrame-screen"
          src="${dynamic-website-inserted-here}" />`
          }}
         />
    </div>

css: 
.iFrame-screen {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -100px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 110%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Just show your code. What you have done .

Comment: in the iframe code you insert in the website, you can manually set the height and width

Comment: If the header and footer have dynamic heights, then it's only possible with JavaScript. You're looking for a viewport height - header height - footer height.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: edited with referral code

Comment: If you're talking about the height of the iframe content, you're going to have to get that height from inside the iframe and send that to the parent window via a message. This might be a good place to start https://gist.github.com/pbojinov/8965299

Answer (score 1):

```
function calcHeight()
{
  //find the height of the internal page
  var the_height = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;

   console.log('Iframe Height is ' + the_height + ' pixels');
};
```

Comment: I am getting this error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined" @Moeez Saiyam

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/first-posts/26249142)

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but you may give this a try. Note that this will fail if you have not a fixed height on the header and footer. The `calc()` calculates the view-height minus the header-height minus the footer-height.

```
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <header id="pageHeader">
    </header>
    <main id="pageMain">
      <iframe src="..."></iframe>
    </main>
    <footer id="pageFooter">
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

with this css.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
header, footer, main {
  display: block;
}
#page {
  min-height: 100%;
}
#pageHeader {
  height: 70px; /* or something else */
}
#pageFooter {
  height: 90px; /* or something else */
}
#pageMain {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 160px); /* 100vh minus (header + footer) */
}
#pageMain iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```